# Is it ok to attack your own village in Travian?

Tags: travian

I have two villages near each other, and I want to move a lot of resources from one to the other, and my merchants are hours away. Is there any problem with me sending troops out of the village with resources, maybe to re-inforce the other village, then attacking my own village with lots of troops, so I can carry all the resources home?

1. Is it possible?
2. Will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Downside : If you defense village has higher level of wall you could lose few units,also if you have neutral defending animals you will have to dismiss them.

Unknown : This should work as in any other attack but I didn't tested it;if traps work for gauls and if hidden resources stay hidden,also if you are in guild if notice is posted that you attacked yourself and if it is counted in guild stats.

Comment: Yes, Gaul traps will trap thier own troops (it's a good way to keep chief or settlers safe), and crannies will protect resources even against your own troops. The attacks will show in the alliance battle reports, but any veteran player will understand, as this is fairly common to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to attack own village, also many times that is really importand and needed way to do some stuffs. 

When this is needed:
- When you want to move Artifact or WW building plan.
- Don't have enough traders and many times faster way to get crop or other resources from own or friendly villages.
- Want to capture own village so you have free slot for creating new village from off village.
- Looks funny, but many times enemy sent reinforcements and good way to kill them, specially when you capture some village and defense is coming from enemy ally. 

What you will not get:
- Attacker points (if you kill own troops)
- Defense points (if you kill own attacking troops)
- Robbering points (if you steal resources)

What need to check:
- To check once again that there is no yours troops,
- To send enough troops that Residence/Palace, Wall and other default defense building don't kill some of your attacking troops. So there is no point if you are at a loss after attack.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and aswell it is faster then trade through market, so when you need move your materials to another village while your market is busy.